# Higher homotopy groups of Seifert fibered spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose i have Seifert fibered homological sphere $\sum = \sum(a_1,...a_m)$, i understand how to compute $\pi_1(\sum)$ using Van-Kampen Theorem, but also im interested in higher homotopy groups,especially in this question, im interested in $\pi_2(\sum)$. Any hints or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the fimension of $\Sigma$? Traditionally, it is 3.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, yes , we work in three dimensional setting.

Comment: Well, nobody knows how to compute all homotopy groups of the 3-dimensional sphere. But if you exclude spherical spaceforms, then the universal covering space is contractible, so...

Comment: I just noticed that you are interested in $\pi_2$. Do you know how to compute $\pi_2(S^3)$? Then you can answer your own question.

Comment: Yes, i know that $\pi_2(S^3) = 0$ through cellular approximation.

Comment: Now you can compute $\pi_2$ of spherical spaceforms and answer your own question.